# Where is my private code exposed as public?

Tags: module, rust, rust-crates

I found out that I have some dead code in my code base but a not getting a dead code warning as expected. I read the [Visibility and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) article from the rust book. I am following the example on creating a "helper module" with code to be used in the crate but not exposed in the public API.

Here is a simplified example of what I think is happening:

```rust
// private module for in-crate usage only
mod foo {
    // everything in the module is pub
    pub struct Foo {}

    impl Foo {
        // I expect to see a dead code warning here. Where is it? ...
        pub fn dead_code() {}
    }
}

use foo::Foo;

// Uh oh, I'm leaking my helper module here!
// But I'm having trouble finding where this occurs in my large code base :(
pub fn get_foo() -> Foo {
    Foo {}
}
```

My question: How do I find the code (`get_foo`) that is "leaking" as public what I intended to be crate-public (`Foo`)? In a real example, there could be one "leak" that has a domino effect of leaking related types.

Comment: Maybe try changing `pub` to `pub(crate)` to further restrict it? - although I'm not sure if I 100% follow what you're asking...

Comment: If the code is used by other (public) functions then it isn't dead.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes I could change Foo to pub(crate). The issue is that I want to be aware of ALL cases where a struct in a private module is made public somehow. I could just mark all such entities as pub(crate), but that seems like bad practice and is not the convention suggested by the rust book. For dead code, I am referring to code that is not used anywhere in the crate.

Comment: **If a module is private, this doesn't imply that its content is private as well**. If you want to ensure that a type isn't exposed to the public API, you have to restrict its visibility (e.g. with `pub(crate)`). It's NOT enough to make its module private.

Comment: I opened a PR to the rust reference if anyone is interested -  https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/pull/830

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pub(crate)` is idiomatic, and would solve your problem.

```rust
// helper module for in-crate usage only
mod foo {
    pub(crate) struct Foo {}

    impl Foo {
        // Dead code warning!
        pub(crate) fn dead_code() {}
    }
}

use foo::Foo;

// pub(crate) prevents leaking helper module here!
pub(crate) fn get_foo() -> Foo {
    Foo{}
}
```

This code generates (multiple) dead code warnings

To demonstrate that `pub(crate)` prevents leaking non-pub items, changing the last function to

```rust
pub fn get_foo() -> Foo {
    Foo{}
}
```

gives a compile error - `error[E0446]: crate-visible type foo::Foo in public interface`

I think the book's example doesn't suggest using `pub(crate)` because that section was written before the book introduced the idea of `pub(restricted)`. If you look at [the RFC for `pub(restricted)`](https://github.com/pnkfelix/rfcs/blob/pub-restricted/text/0000-pub-restricted.md), it specifically calls out what you did

> (2.) you can define X as a pub item in some submodule (and import into the root of the module tree via use).
>
> But: Sometimes neither of these options is really what you want.

Comment: Thanks! You are exactly right about the book. (Actually I just noticed it is the rust _reference_, not the book.) That section has not been updated since `pub(restricted)` was stabilized. A section about that feature is there, but the part about "helper module" still seems misleading. Anyways, I will adjust my practice to use `pub(restricted)` more liberally.